# Notifications with CouchDB using C#

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, couchdb

I want to implement with C# a CouchDB client to push notifications when documents from a CouchDB view are changed, i.e. monitor views.

There are several CouchDB api attempts [SharpChouch](http://code.google.com/p/couchbrowse/source/browse/trunk/SharpCouch/SharpCouch.cs), [Relax-Net](http://code.google.com/p/relax-net/) but nothing has been done around notifications. Is this even possible to implement with CouchDB or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the asynchronous C# client MyCouch, which has documentation on how to consume the Changes API: https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/wiki/documentation#consume-the-changes-feed

Note. There are two NuGet packages. One that is [for CouchDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyCouch) and one [for Cloudant](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyCouch.Cloudant), that offers Cloudant specific features.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. You need to take a looks at `_changes` handler. Additionally you can filter changes using `filter` functions.

[CouchDB. The Defenitive Guide: Change Notifications](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/notifications.html)